# Problem with baby stool

Tags: toddler

My 15 months daughter passes stool 3 times a day. She started this habit last week. Before that she had passed her stool like after 2 or 3 days and that was hard.

She is active, healthy every thing is normal.

Could anyone tell me is it normal?

Comment: Not sure what the right tag for 'stool' is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Children passing stool on a variable basis is not uncommon, and not in and of itself a reason for concern normally.  Often stool changes are due to eating habits; for example, a diet high in fiber (veggies/fruit) will yield softer, more frequent stools, while a diet primarily consisting of meats and cheeses will likely yield infrequent, hard stools.

Two to three times a day is still well within 'normal'; both of my (13mo and 33mo) children are in that range.  Both are pretty good about veggie/whole fruit consumption, and thus have pretty soft stools.  When they eat more meat/yogurt, they become less frequent and harder.

That said, this is not a site for medical advice, so if you have some concern, you should certainly talk to your pediatrician.